# How to get name of view class in codeigniter from javascript?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to get class name of my view from js.

say my url is

```
http://localhost/test/index.php/mytest/newtest/34
```

here newtest is the name of view class. I want to get this class name from my js.
I have searched for it on google but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname;
pathArray = pathArray.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
pathArray = pathArray.split( '/' );
console.log(pathArray);
```

With this Javascript you will get all parts from your url as array. There you will know which element is the one you are looking for..

Comment: this will only work if no modifications have been made to the path via routes

Comment: @bizzehdee this will work directly on current URL ..
CI don't have JS predefined Controller and Method so there is no standard method to get current Method or Controller

Comment: i was simply adding to the answer pointing out that this method will only work if @ehp doesnt change the URL with routes

Comment: @bizzehdee it will work always. Its pure JS for catching current url elements. What ever you have change in your rotes you will search at your url some for specific word not strict method name... :)